# Horizontal / Vertical Alignment Not Working in RelativePanel

Tags: xaml, windows-10, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to create a `RelativePanel` (for reflow purposes) with two `Image`'s and a `StackPanel` in it. When in a "small screen" view, I want it to lay out vertically in a column: `Image`, `StackPanel`, `Image`. It does this just fine, but the problem is that the `StackPanel` has a height of 0, so the bottom `Image` is smack up against it. I want the `Image` to snap to the bottom of the screen. However, `VerticalAlignment="Bottom"` refuses to work. After a little more testing, I've found that `HorizontalAlignment` doesn't work, either. Does aligning not work properly in a `RelativePanel`? Or is there a special way to do it?

Here is the full XAML:

```
<RelativePanel>
    <Image Width="100" x:Name="AppleImage" Source="/Assets/Images/apple.png" Margin="10" Tapped="Add_Apple" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <StackPanel x:Name="TotalStackPanel" Margin="10" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="Total" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <GridView x:Name="TotalFruitGrid" SelectionChanged="Remove_Fruit">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=image.Source}" Height="50"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
    </StackPanel>
    <Image Width="100" x:Name="OrangeImage" Source="/Assets/Images/orange.png" Margin="10" Tapped="Add_Orange" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
</RelativePanel>
```

Comment: You need to be using the [attached properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.relativepanel.aspx#attachedmembers) of `RelativePanel` or you're not getting what it's used for. Check out some [examples of use](http://visuallylocated.com/post/2015/04/09/In-depth-with-the-Windows-RelativePanel.aspx) and you'll probably find pretty quick why just HorizontalAlignment's aren't doing much for you. :)

Comment: Ah! I knew of some of them (Below, Above, RightOf, etc.) but never saw the complete list. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.relativepanel.aspx#attachedmembers) for various Attached Properties of Relative Panel, that will help you do things like alignments.

You can do basic Horizontal alignments this way:

```
<RelativePanel Background="Black">
    <Rectangle x:Name="RedRect" Width="100" Height="100" 
               RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" 
               Fill="Red" />
    <Rectangle x:Name="BlueRect" Height="100"
               RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" 
               RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" 
               Fill="Blue"
               RelativePanel.Below="RedRect"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="YellowRect" Width="100" Height="100" 
               RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" 
               RelativePanel.Below="BlueRect"
               Fill="Yellow" />
</RelativePanel>
```

And above code will show the RelativePanel something like this:

[image: Alignment in RelativePanel]